# Style a component's [aria-checked="true"] using Material UI's makeStyle

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a check box (**not** a Material-UI checkbox) that I'd like to style using it's `aria-checked="true"` attribute via makeStyles. I see in the Material-UI docs that you can style pseudo selectors as such:

```
'&:hover': { /* … */ },
```

But I haven't been able to make this work for the aria attribute? Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) is largely the same as in CSS. `&` is used to refer to the generated class (`classes.myCheckboxStyles` in my example below) and then further selectors can be added within the quotes (e.g. `"&[aria-checked=true]"`).

Below is a working example demonstrating the syntax:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  myCheckboxStyles: {
    border: "1px black solid",
    color: "white",
    "&[aria-checked=true]": {
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    }
  }
});
export default function Checkboxes() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <span
        onClick={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        aria-checked={checked}
        className={classes.myCheckboxStyles}
      >
        X
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit aria-checked styling]

Comment: Hey Ryan, I'm actually trying to apply the styling to a non Material UI check box

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use `aria-checked="true"` to activate MUI checkbox, but it doesn't work. So, in my view, you should try using `onMouseEnter` to activate MUI checkbox. You can try this:

```js
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

export default function Checkboxes() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        checked={checked}
        onMouseEnter={() => setChecked(true)}
        onChange={handleChange}
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Select with checkboxes and sub headers]

Comment: Im trying to aply the styling to a non Material UI check box